# Binary classifier testing with minority positive data

Tags: cross-validation, hypothesis-testing

I have a question about a testing methodology for a binary classifier, that I'm not entirely sure how to describe. So apologies if this has been answered many times before but I haven't had much luck searching for it.

I'm attempting to test a binary classifier where the positive class is a tiny minority of the data, approximately 1% of the actual data. My question is: what is the best way of testing a classifier so that a failure to classify something as positive actually counts towards the accuracy score. For instance, if the classifier always said Negative, it would still be 99% accurate.

I've been trying 5-fold cross-validation but obviously the above case occurs and it always give an amazing score. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A useful tip for a search term: this problem is often called the "Class Imbalance Problem".

Comment: Thanks. I've been testing the Matthews Correlation Co-efficient which seems a good place to start. Is there anyone with more know how that could comment on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a threshold involved in the classifier, a standard [ROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve should be a good measure. It is a plot where one axis represents accuracy within the positive class, and the other within the negative.
A classifier that always says negative would have a TPR (true positive rate) of 0%.